# Emacs: Jump back to previous query-replace location

Tags: emacs

I do this a lot: `[M-%]` to `query-replace`, then hit `[y]` a few times, then I'm past the area where I'm changing things so I hit `[q]` to be done.

Then I'd like to get the cursor back to where I was, so here's where it gets awkward. I `[C-_]` to `undo` the last replace, then move the cursor on character, then `undo` again to redo the last replace. Now the cursor's up where I've been editing, but there has to be a better way.

(I'm happy to get back to either where I started the replace, or where the last replace happened.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-SPC</kbd> jumps to the mark (which was automatically set as Blrfl pointed out), and then pops the previous mark off the local mark ring (so you can repeat the process to move to previous marks).

I think this is preferable to `exchange-point-and-mark`, as the latter reactivates the mark, highlighting the region in transient-mark-mode, which you wouldn't want in this case. (Unless you wanted to jump back and forth between the point you started at and the location of the final replacement, in which case `exchange-point-and-mark` *would* be exactly what you wanted.)

Comment: Think you meant `C-u C-SPC`.  `C-u SPC` inserts four spaces.

Comment: (I took the liberty of correcting answer as @Blrfl suggested.)

Comment: Great! As a bonus, not need to hit `q` before the `C-u C-SPC`.

Comment: Whoops. Yes indeed, and thanks for the edit. My fingers know what to type, even if I don't ;)

Answer (score 1):

After you quit, the mark will be where you started and the point will be where you stopped.  `C-x C-x` will swap the two, putting the point where you started.

Comment: As @phils mentioned, this does highlight the region which isn't ideal for me. Although `C-x C-x C-g` is a sort of workaround.

Comment: Didn't even think of the highlighting issue since Emacs didn't do that when I started using it (paleolithic age) and when it did I set `transient-mark-mode` to `nil` to make it behave the old way.